# Discrete time Markov Chain - Long-term frequency

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let's say I have the following scenario:

> A mouse is put into a maze that's constructed as below:
>
> [image]
>
> There are 9 rooms with connections between the rooms as indicated with
>   a "gap" in the "walls". Assume the mouse moves through the rooms at
>   random and that self-transitions are allowed. That is, if there are
>   $k$ ways to leave a room (or stay in the same room), it chooses each
>   of these with equal probability.

**Question:**

What is the long-term expected fraction of time the mouse spends in each room?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard application of Markov chain convergence theory. You can abstract the room configuration as a graph, with 6 vertices having degree 2 (leaves), two side vertices degree 4 and central vertex degree 5: because of self-loops as pointed out in comment belwo. Let $\mu_i$ be the long-term probability of the mouse spending in room $i$, and let $p_{ij}$ be the transition probability from room $i$ to room $j$. Then one must have
$$ \sum_i \mu_i p_{ij} = \mu_j$$

It's easy to see that $\mu_i \propto d_i$ where $d_i$ is the degree of room $i$ is one (projective) solution; to show uniqueness look up the proof of Perron-Frobenius Theorem.

Comment: Since self-transitions are allowed, doesn't that mean there are 6 vertices with degree 2? I.e., state 1 has 1/2 probability of self transitioning and 1/2 probability of transitioning to state 4? Similarly for state 4, it has 1/4 probability of transitioning to itself, state 1, state 5, and state 7, respectively, right?

Comment: Yes. The rest follows the same. In fact if there are leaves, then the chain is not irreducible.

Comment: Leaves are not related to reducibility. Here, if there are leaves, the chain is **periodic**. Note that periodicity would not change the fact that the proportion of time spent in each state converges, hence the addition of loops is (slightly artificial, if you ask me, and) not needed to solve the question.